# getting option content using php DOMXPath

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

I'm trying to get product sizes from all option elements or particular select tag that has an:

```
<select id="prodSize" name="prodSize">
    <option value="9274">10D</option>
    <option value="9275">10DD</option>
    <option value="9276">10E</option>
    <option value="9277">10F</option>
    <option value="9279">10G</option>
    <option value="9288">12D</option>
    <option value="9289">12DD</option>
    <option value="9290">12E</option>
    <option value="9291">12F</option>
    <option value="9301">14D</option>
    <option value="9302">14DD</option>
    <option value="9303">14E</option>
    <option value="9304">14F</option>
    <option value="9305">14FF</option>
    <option value="9315">16D</option>
    <option value="9317">16E</option>
    <option value="9318">16F</option>
    <option value="9319">16FF</option>
    <option value="9320">16G</option>
</select>
```

I have tried using `$x("//select[@id='prodSize']/option/text()")` in chrome dev tools and it returned me all the values with no problem, but when I'm tying to get it with DOMXPath:

```
$options = $xpath->query("//select[@id='prodSize']/option/text()");
```

or:

```
$options = $xpath->query("*/select[@id='prodSize']/option");
```

I get:

```
object(DOMNodeList)#40 (1) { ["length"]=> int(0) } object(DOMNodeList)#29 (1) { ["length"]=> int(0) }
object(DOMNodeList)#39 (1) { ["length"]=> int(0) } object(DOMNodeList)#41 (1) { ["length"]=> int(0) }
```

I have added full code for clarity:

```
scrapCatUrl('http://.../shop-management/categories/maternity-lingerie.aspx',  "//ul[@class='lvl2 visible']/li/a/@href");

 function scrapCatUrl($path, $query){

    $xpath = scrap($path);
    $links = $xpath->query($query);
    foreach($links as $link){
        echo 'Category'.' - '.$url.$link->nodeValue . '<br>';
        scrapProdUrl($url.$link->nodeValue);
    }
}
 function scrapProdUrl($path){

    $xpath = scrap($path);
    $links = $xpath->query("//a[@class='thumbObj']/@href");
    $i = 0;
    foreach($links as $link){
        echo 'Product'.' - '.$url.$link->nodeValue . '<br>';
        getProdData($url.$link->nodeValue);
        if($i > 2){
            die();
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
function getProdData($path){
    $xpath = scrap($path);
    $description = $xpath->query("//meta[@name='description']/@content");
    $keywords = $xpath->query("//meta[@name='keywords']/@content");
    $title = $xpath->query("//h4[@class='h4-productdetail']/text()");
    $price = $xpath->query("//div[@class='productDetail']/span[@class='price']/text()");
    $images = $xpath->query("//div[@class='imgs']/img/@src");
    $fullDescription = $xpath->query("//div[@class='flash']/following-sibling::div[@class='clearer']/preceding-sibling::text()[preceding-sibling::div[@class='flash']]");
    $options = $xpath->query("//select[@id='prodSize']/option/text()");

    echo 'Meta Description'.' - '.$description->item(0)->nodeValue. '<br>';
    echo 'Meta Keywords'.' - '.$keywords->item(0)->nodeValue. '<br>';
    echo 'Title'.' - '.$title->item(0)->nodeValue. '<br>';
    echo 'Price'.' - '.$price->item(0)->nodeValue. '<br>';
    if($images->length > 1){
        foreach($images as $image){
            echo '<img src="'.$url.$image->nodeValue.'" />'. '<br>';
        }
    }
    else{
        echo '<img src="'.$url.$image->nodeValue.'" />'. '<br>';
    }
    foreach($options as $option){
        echo $option->nodeValue;
    }



}
 function scrap($path){
    $ch = curl_init($path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $page = curl_exec($ch);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($page);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
    return $xpath;
}
```

I have tried few ways that people suggested here but getting the same result. I have no problems getting any other element from a page, title, images, descriptions everything except this one.

Comment: try to enable error reporting (`error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`).. `function scrap($path, $query){` requires two parameters but you only provided one: `$xpath = scrap($path);`

Comment: @kevinabelita errors enabled, no problems found, still  getting everything except sizes :(

Comment: @kevinabelita I think this size list is generated by javascript is it possible to get elements after all javascript functions have been initiated?

Comment: View the original page source. If it does not contain the options that you want, this is probably populated via javascript. Domxpath doesn't seem to be capable of that. You could use [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) or the [php-phantomjs](https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs) wrapper.